# Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView

Tags: android, admob, native, ads

I'm getting this error while adding native ads (AdMob)

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView
>
> Help me out..
>   My Code is...

```
   `

public class Raining extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    NativeExpressAdView adView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_natural);

        adView = (NativeExpressAdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

        //Top ads
        MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-8458533793773924/5313130080");

        AdView mAdView1 = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView1);
        AdRequest adRequest1 = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView1.loadAd(adRequest1);
}}

********

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/aa"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id_Top">

    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_priview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/adView1"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/rain" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView_priview"
        android:padding="1dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_main_activty_preview_id"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Preview"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_main_activty_cancel_id"

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:elevation="7dp"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat" />
    </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

            <com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                ads:adSize="280x150"
                ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id">

            </com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView>
        </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>'
```

Comment: show me your code

Comment: NativeExpressAdView adView = (NativeExpressAdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

Comment: in logcat, it is showing above line .

Comment: show me your xml file?

Answer (score 1):

Try this and upvote if it works

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ad_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            ads:adSize="280x150"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id">

        </com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Java Code:

```
     LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ad_layout);
     // Create a native express ad. The ad size and ad unit ID must be set before calling
     // loadAd.
     mNativeExpressAdView = new NativeExpressAdView(this);
     mNativeExpressAdView.setAdSize(new AdSize(400, 100));
     mNativeExpressAdView.setAdUnitId("myAdUnitId");

     // Create an ad request.
     AdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();

     // Optionally populate the ad request builder.
     adRequestBuilder.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR);

     // Add the NativeExpressAdView to the view hierarchy.
     linearLayout.addView(mNativeExpressAdView);

     // Start loading the ad.
     mNativeExpressAdView.loadAd(adRequestBuilder.build());
```

Comment: I want to implement native ads. the above error is while performing native

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference

Comment: LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ad_layout); did you add this line?

Comment: <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ad_layout"
This line?